# Information from two separate databases in PeopleSoft

Tags: database, peoplesoft

I was told today that you couldn't pull data from two separate tables on two separate databases in PeopleSoft simultaneously. But, this is a database. Ideally, you should be able to do this. Has anyone ever pulled this off and if so, were you able to accomplish this in PS nVision?

Answer (score 1):

I see two main approaches to your question :

- Create interface between the two PIA using Web Services(you mentionned only separated PIA but I assume we are talking of two separate PeopleSoft module , like HR and FSCM).However I'm not sure it will do the trick with nVision (i've never use it , so you must find a way to consume the Web Servie through it)
- A simpler solution (but trickier to maintain) is to create a dblink to the second database and create your query by using it. Again, compliance of this solution with nVision has to be proven.

First solution allows access other PIA's data.

Second one, allows access to othe database containing Peoplesoft data (or anything else)